# How to inspect keyword arguments for method

Tags: ruby

Given the following Ruby 2.x method, how can I inspect the keyword arguments?

```
def for_account(token_id: nil, email: nil, password: nil)
  puts "arguments are: ??"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def for_account(token_id: nil, email: nil, password: nil)
  puts "arguments are: ??"
end

p method(:for_account).parameter
# => [[:key, :token_id], [:key, :email], [:key, :password]]
```

Comment: sorry, I meant the values of the arguments inside the method, similar to javascript's arguments https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments